# Change admin layout in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working in cakephp, and I have the following two lines in my /app/config/routes.php file:

```
/**
 * ...and setup admin routing
 */
 Router::connect('/admin/:controller/:action/*', array('action' => null, 'prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true, 'layout' => 'admin' ));
/**
 * ...and set the admin default page
 */
 Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'profiles', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true, 'layout' => 'admin'));
```

I also have a layout at /app/views/layouts/admin.ctp

However, the layout is not changed when I visit admin URLs

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Create a `app/app_controller.php` and put this in:

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {

    function beforeFilter() {
        if (isset($this->params['prefix']) && $this->params['prefix'] == 'admin') {
            $this->layout = 'admin';
        } 
    }

}
```

Don't forget to call `parent::beforeFilter();` in your controllers if you use it in other controllers.

Semi related to the question, you don't need the routes defined, you just need to enable `Routing.admin` config option and set it to `admin` in the `app/config/core.php`. (CakePHP 1.2)

Comment: Thanks! On the Routing.admin config option:
1. That has been changed to routing.prefix
2. I changed it because it did not provide the 'layout' option, but now that is irrelavent
3. Even with the Routing.admin (or prefix)on, I still need the second route for an index page

Comment: your second route is still needed, however i dont believe you need 'layout' => 'admin' all that is doing is adding a param onto your url (if you set pass) that will only be available on that page. the Routing.prefixes does something similar to your first route :)

Answer (score 3):

Add this code in beforeFilter() function in 
**app_controller.php**

```
<?php    

class AppController extends Controller {

function beforeFilter() {
    if (isset($this->params['prefix']) && $this->params['prefix'] == 'admin') {
        $this->layout = 'admin';
    } else {
       $this->layout = 'user';  
    } 

    }

}
?>
```

Set layout='admin' in 
**routes.php**

```
<?php    
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index','add', 'admin' => true,'prefix' => 'admin','layout' => 'admin'));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For CakePHP 3.X you should edit your `src/View/AppView.php` file and add the following code to your `initialize()` method:

```
public function initialize()
{
    if ($this->request->getParam('prefix') === 'admin') {
        $this->layout = 'Plugin.layout';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the approaches above are good but if you are looking to change the layout for every page when logged in you might try the following using Auth Component

```
function beforeFilter() {
    if ($this->Auth->user()) {
        $this->layout = 'admin';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For cakephp 3.0 you can set a view variable by calling Auth->user in the beforeRender in AppController. This is my beforeRender:

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    ///...other stuff

    $userRole = $this->Auth->user();
    $this->set('userRole', $userRole['role']);
}
```